# Fill a string buffer from a thread

Tags: rust

With `hyper`, I need to make an HTTP connection and read the results.
I want to wrap the whole thing in a timeout,
so I start a thread
and use [`recv_timeout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#method.recv_timeout) to wait for it.

Wrapping just the [`send`](https://hyper.rs/hyper/v0.9.8/hyper/client/request/struct.Request.html#method.send) works,
but I want to also wrap [`read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string).
Here is the code:

```
fn send_request(url: &str) -> Result<Response, MyAppError> {
    let mut c = Client::new();
    let mut req = c.get(url);
    req.send().map_err(|e| MyAppError::TcpError(e))
}

fn get_url(url: &str, mut buf: &mut String) -> Result<u16, MyAppError> {
    let mut resp = send_request(url)?;
    resp.read_to_string(&mut buf).map_err(|e| MyAppError::ReadError(e))?;
    Ok(resp.status.to_u16())
}

fn get_url_with_timeout_2(url: &str, mut buf: &mut String) -> Result<u16, MyAppError> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let url = url.to_owned();
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        match tx.send(get_url(&url, &mut buf)) {
            Ok(()) => {} // everything good
            Err(_) => {} // we have been released, no biggie
        }
    });
    match rx.recv_timeout(Duration::from_millis(5000)) {
        Ok(resp) => resp,
        Err(_) => Err(MyAppError::Timeout),
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get a compiler error:

```
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/main.rs:53:25: 58:4 tx:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<std::result::Result<u16, MyAppError>>, url:std::string::String, buf:&mut std::string::String]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:53:11
   |
53 |   let t = thread::spawn(move || {
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: type must outlive the static lifetime
```

How can I pass the buffer to the thread,
let it fill it,
and then print out the buffer back on the main thread?

(This is Rust 1.15.1.)

[This repository](https://github.com/pjungwir/rust-thread-read-to-string) gives a complete `main.rs` and shows three examples for getting the webpage:

1. With no timeout.
2. With a timeout just on `send`.
3. With a timeout on the whole thing.

If you take out 3, it all compiles and runs.
What can I change about 3 to make that work too?

By the way, making a web request is really just the "occasion" for this question. I've already seen [this question about doing a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181719/what-is-the-correct-way-in-rust-to-create-a-timeout-for-a-thread-or-a-function). My own interest is not the timeout per se, but about how to fill up a buffer on one thread and read it on another.

[Share mutable object between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373255/share-mutable-object-between-threads) suggests using `Arc` and `Mutex` to safely share data between threads. Here is an attempt at that:

```
fn get_url_with_timeout_3(url: &str) -> Result<(u16, String), MyAppError> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let url = url.to_owned();
    let shbuf = Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new()));
    let shbuf2 = shbuf.clone();
    let t = thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut c = Client::new();
        let mut req = c.get(&url);
        let mut ret = match req.send() {
            Ok(mut resp) => {
                let mut buf2 = shbuf2.lock().unwrap();
                match resp.read_to_string(&mut buf2) {
                    Ok(_) => Ok(resp.status.to_u16()),
                    Err(e) => Err(MyAppError::ReadError(e)),
                }
            }
            Err(e) => Err(MyAppError::TcpError(e)),
        };

        match tx.send(ret) {
            Ok(()) => {} // everything good
            Err(_) => {} // we have been released, no biggie
        }
    });
    match rx.recv_timeout(Duration::from_millis(5000)) {
        Ok(maybe_status_code) => {
            let buf2 = shbuf.lock().unwrap();
            Ok((maybe_status_code?, *buf2))
        }
        Err(_) => Err(MyAppError::Timeout),
    }
}
```

This gives me the error `cannot move out of borrowed content` for trying to return `*buf2` (which makes sense, since it would be leaking data out of the `Mutex`), but I'm not sure how to express this in a structure where Rust can see the pattern.

If the request thread times out, it holds the lock forever — but I never try to read the buffer, so who cares. If the request thread finishes, it releases the lock and goes away, and the main thread will hold the only reference. I can reason that it is safe, but I'm not sure how to convince the compiler.

I'm not allowed to answer this question since it is supposedly a duplicate, but I've added 3 working implementations to [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/pjungwir/rust-thread-read-to-string/tree/45c3aacc5ff0bd0df32aff67a1d240948f047874) using the ideas from the comments.

Comment: Likely duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31373255/155423; but also http://stackoverflow.com/q/29540407/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/40035731/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/28654978/155423 (and other searches for "thread mutable" and friends).

Comment: It is not clear to me how to apply those answers to my question, so perhaps you or someone else could explain. I'll add an attempt using Arc+Mutex that also doesn't compile.

Comment: I think in your second example you will either have to return Result<(u16, Arc<Mutex<String>>), MyAppError> or return a clone of buf2

Comment: Both suggestions actually work @Ankur. Thanks for your help! The only other improvement I wish for is to pass in a pre-allocated `String` (like the first two examples) rather than returning one, but I haven't figured that one out yet.

Comment: Actually, building on the "return the mutex" suggestion, I can also *allocate* the mutex outside the function and pass it in. Even nicer!

Comment: Allocating the `Mutex` outside the threads (including the allocated `String`) is exactly what http://stackoverflow.com/a/31373349/155423 does. It also [links to another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42195774/155423) that shows how to get the `String` back when the threads are done, so you don't need to return the `Arc<Mutex<String>>`.